# Rename multiple "str1 - str2.txt" files to "str2 - str1.txt"

Tags: regex, bash, unix, command-line

I have many files in a directory named like:

```
str1 - str2.txt
```

How to rename them in bash to:

```
str2 - str1.txt
```

- `str1` - is a string containing alphanumeric characters, spaces and in some cases one or more `-` characters.
- `str2` - is a string containing only alphanumeric characters.

I can rename them one by one using `rename 'y/str1 - str2/str2 - str1/' *` command, but I would like to find an appropriate regex to rename all files in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I am using sed to generate a list of commands to run. You can capture it into a file and execute the file.

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\) - \([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)\.txt/mv "\1 - \2.txt" "\2 - \1.txt"/g' \
   | grep "^mv" > mv_commands
## Verify that the correct mv commands were generated in the "mv_commands" file
sh commands
```

Comment: Didn't get you. Did you try the above? What is the output you got? `\1` and `\2` represent regex matching groups, not actual `1` and `2`. If it did not work, can you give some examples where it did not work?

Comment: Some "prankster" drops a file named `mv;rm -rf ~` in that directory you could have real trouble. You want `sed -nr '/^([[:alnum:]]*) - ([[:alnum:]]*)\.txt$/s//mv \2 \1.txt/p'`, if nothing else because it's a bad habit to get into, letting your guard down like that.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome tool called `mmv` can do stuff like this

```
$ touch "str1 - str2.txt"
$ mmv -v "str* - str*.txt" "str#2 - str#1.txt"
str1 - str2.txt -> str2 - str1.txt : done
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 hashier  wheel  0 Sep 21 20:05 str2 - str1.txt
$
```

of course you need to adapt it a bit to your needs, but `mmv`, `mcp`, ... are really powerfull

Answer (score 1):

**To rename all files in current directory using script**,

```
list=`ls *-*.txt`

for files in $list
do
  mv $files `echo "$files" | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' | gawk '{match($0, /([^-]*)
  (-+)(.*)/, a); print a[3],a[2],a[1]".txt"}' | tr -d [:space:]`
done
```